# Using facebook login credentials across several classes and fragments

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

I'm creating an app which requires users to login via Facebook. I am able to retrieve their login details (user id, user name) in that activity by using sessions and theopen graph.

However i want to use it in other activities and fragments across the application. For example displaying options that are specific to logged in users.

However the problem is that I cant use intents to pass the user's details because the activities are not called from one another.

I have tried using public variables but this doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea how to easily retrieve Facebook login credentials across an application?

Comment: use shared Preferences and store credentials in that and retrieve them where you want..

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy how do you do that?

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy thanks figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static variable and access the credentials between classes in that way.

```
public static class FacebookCredentials
{
  private static String credentials;

  public static String getCredentials()
  {
    return credentials;
  }

  public static void setCredentials(String credentials)
  {
    FacebookCredentials.credentials = credentials;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Facebook SDK for Android 3.0?

If so, you should use the "active session" mechanism (Session.setActiveSession(), Session.openActiveSession(), Session.getActiveSession(), etc).  You should be able to call Session.getActiveSession from any activity/fragment since it's a static variable within the Session class.

Comment: yes i am but i don't want to have to repeat that code every time

Comment: I guess I don't really follow. Is Session s = Session.getActiveSession(); really that much code to add? You'll have to add the same amount of code even if you can pass it in an intent.